# Update one list with respect to another list in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm very new in python. I just stuck in one problem.
I have two lists, like -

```py
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [3,6,8,9,1,2,4,0,5]
```

Now I have to check each value of list1 with that it is present in list2 or not. If all the value of list1 is present in list2 then update the list2 by removing extra values from list2. So list2 will be like -

```
list2 = [3,1,2,4,5]
```

Tried to do this with nested loop. but it is reading only 1st value. how can I do that?

Comment: "Tried to do this with nested loop. but it is reading only 1st value" - we would need you to include your code in order to tell you what goes wrong with it.

Comment: I would use a `set` and a list comprehension but please show your attempt with the loop so that we can tell you the problem and you can learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the many options for performing the task

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [3, 6, 8, 9, 1, 2, 4, 0, 5]
list2 = [num for num in list2 if num in list1 and set(list1).issubset(list2)]
```

Comment: You missed one detail from the question. This should only be done "If all the value of list1 is present in list2".

Comment: you could just add: `if (set(list1).issubset(list2)):` before performing the task

Comment: you can bring the condition set(list1).issubset(list2) before the generator and execute it:
```
if set(list1).issubset(list2):
    list2 = [num for num in list2 if num in list1]
```